# AttributeError: 'EventView' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django

i am working on a calendar application.i am facing following error on my web page .this is my views.py .can someone please help me in it. Thanks in advance

### views.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.shortcuts import render
from events.models import Event
import datetime
import calendar
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from events.utils import EventCalendar
# Register your models here.

class EventView(Event):
    list_display = ['day', 'start_time', 'end_time', 'notes']
    change_list_template = 'admin/events/change_list.html'

    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        after_day = request.GET.get('day__gte', None)
        extra_context = extra_context or {}

        if not after_day:
            d = datetime.date.today()
        else:
            try:
                split_after_day = after_day.split('-')
                d = datetime.date(year=int(split_after_day[0]), month=int(split_after_day[1]), day=1)
            except:
                d = datetime.date.today()

        previous_month = datetime.date(year=d.year, month=d.month, day=1)  # find first day of current month
        previous_month = previous_month - datetime.timedelta(days=1)  # backs up a single day
        previous_month = datetime.date(year=previous_month.year, month=previous_month.month,
                                       day=1)  # find first day of previous month

        last_day = calendar.monthrange(d.year, d.month)
        next_month = datetime.date(year=d.year, month=d.month, day=last_day[1])  # find last day of current month
        next_month = next_month + datetime.timedelta(days=1)  # forward a single day
        next_month = datetime.date(year=next_month.year, month=next_month.month,
                                   day=1)  # find first day of next month

        extra_context['previous_month'] = reverse('admin:events_event_changelist') + '?day__gte=' + str(
            previous_month)
        extra_context['next_month'] = reverse('admin:events_event_changelist') + '?day__gte=' + str(next_month)

        cal = EventCalendar()
        html_calendar = cal.formatmonth(d.year, d.month, withyear=True)
        html_calendar = html_calendar.replace('<td ', '<td  width="150" height="150"')
        extra_context['calendar'] = mark_safe(html_calendar)
        return super(EventAdmin, self).changelist_view(request, extra_context)
```

### this is the error in my terminal

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\vikas
>   visking\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.p
>   y", line 35, in inner
>       response = get_response(request)   File "C:\Users\vikas visking\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py",
>   li ne 97, in **call**
>       response = self.process_response(request, response)   File "C:\Users\vikas
>   visking\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\clickjacking.p
>   y", line 26, in process_response
>       if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None: AttributeError: 'EventView' object has no attribute 'get' [18/Apr/2018 21:23:56] "GET
>   /events/ HTTP/1.1" 500 56977

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if you are trying to create a custom model admin. In that case, you should be subclassing `admin.ModelAdmin`.

```
from django.contrib import admin

class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['day', 'start_time', 'end_time', 'notes']
    change_list_template = 'admin/events/change_list.html'

admin.site.register(Event, EventAdmin)
```

This code belongs in your `admin.py`, not your views.

Comment: Yes sir this code belongs to admin.py but i am trying to make a custom views for users in views.py

Comment: If you're writing views then I wouldn't start with model admin code. It's not very re-usable.

Comment: I know sir thats why i need ur help. I want to make the same module for users what should i do..thanks in advance sir you replied

Comment: I can't convert that code to a normal view for you. I suggest you start with the simplest view possible, and begin to add functionality to it. When you get stuck, then ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
class EventView(ListView):
    model = Event
```